# Mail design working in mailchimp template, but not in mail clients

Tags: html, css, mailchimp, mailing

I have created a template in mailchimp programming myself the html with their respective styles. Everything works fine in the mailchip template viewer. But the moment to see the result in mail clients, some styles are ignored. In the template I am using an image as a background and some text and div elements superimposed on it, using absolute positions. In mail clients, these positions are ignored and the content is displayed as a single column. Does anyone have any solution to this?
[image]
Thanks in advance.

I attach the implemented code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
      <head>
        <!--[if gte mso 15]>
        <xml>
          <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            <o:AllowPNG />
            <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
          </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        </xml>
        <![endif]-->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow" rel="stylesheet">

      </head>
      <body>
        <div>
          <div id="coverImg" style="background-color:black;opacity:.15;width:650px;height:890px;position:absolute;z-index:1;"></div>
          <img id="fondoImg" style="position:absolute;z-index:0;width:650px;" src="imageURL1" alt="fa94319f-53fe-4c6a-b34b-8660dfb1ba28.jpg">
          <h1 id="tituloTxt" style="position:absolute;z-index:2;font-size:40px;top:27px;left:275px;">
            <strong>XXXXXXXXXXXX</strong> <br> XXXXXXXXXX</h1>
            <div id="containerText">
              <p>XXXXXX: *|NOMBRE|*</p>
              <p>XXXXX *|VALORADEUD|*.</p>
              <p style="text-align:center;">XXXXXXXXX</p>
              <center>
                <a href="randomURL</a>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div style="margin-top:50px;">
                  <h3 class="lista" style="display:inline;">XXXXXX: </h3> <h3 style="display:inline;">
                    *|CEDULA_RUC|*
                  </h3>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div style="display:inline;">
                  <h3 class="lista" style="display:inline;">XXXXXXX: </h3> <h3 style="display:inline;"> *|NOMBRE|*
                  </h3>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div style="display:inline;">
                  <h3 class="lista" style="display:inline;">XXXXXXX: </h3> <h3 style="display:inline;">*|VALORADEUD|*</h3>
                </div>
              </center>
            </div>
            <p id="txt1">xxxxxxxxxx,</p>
            <p id="txt2">xxxxxxxxxx <br> xxxxxxxxxxxx</p>

          </div>
          <style type="text/css">
            body{
                font-family:'PT Sans Narrow',sans-serif;
            }
            #fondoImg{
                position:absolute;
                z-index:0;
                width:650px;
            }
            #coverImg{
                background-color:black;
                opacity:.15;
                width:650px;
                height:890px;
                position:absolute;
                z-index:1;
            }
            #tituloTxt{
                position:absolute;
                z-index:2;
                font-size:40px;
                top:27px;
                left:275px;
            }
            #containerText{
                position:absolute;
                z-index:1;
                top:200px;
                left:45px;
                height:470px;
                width:530px;
                background-color:white;
                padding-left:20px;
                padding-right:20px;
                text-align:justify;
            }
            #txt1{
                position:absolute;
                z-index:1;
                color:white;
                left:270px;
                top:680px;
            }
            #txt2{
                position:absolute;
                z-index:1;
                color:white;
                left:185px;
                top:710px;
                text-align:center;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            .lista{
                color:red;
            }
    </style>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi Frank, email template development is not as straight-forward as webpage design. I've found Litmus.com to be a great way to test code. That said, it's not free. No I don't work for them :-)

Comment: Email templates are tricky. Each client reads them with its own quirks. Old school teaches to go crazy on tables with embedded css where the new school is all about litmus.com and similar tools which take care of the testing for you. Either case post the template or at least the main part that goes outside of the element.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, attach the code. I hope you can help me.

Comment: _“using relative positions”_ - where, I only see _absolute_ positioning everywhere? I would generally recommend to try and avoid (absolute) positioning as much as possible inside an e-mail template - good chance this will simply get filtered out completely, at least by web mail interfaces, out of concerns that you could try and use it to overlay UI elements. Maybe a solution that has the image “drag” the rest of the content over it via a negative `margin-bottom` might work. (And the rest of the content laid out in “normal flow” then, not positioned.)

Comment: I edited the post, the relative position was an error the moment I wrote it.  
 @Cbroe were right, mail clients ignored the style of absolute positions, but the negative margin did not work either. I had to use a div with the background image property and nest all the content inside that div.